# Getting link text with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

How would one parse the content inside these tags, assuming the link is dynamic?

```
<h3 class="lvtitle">
<a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Chicago-Chicago-XXX-Audio-CD-/351478948979?hash=item51d5c72473" 
 class="vip" title="Click this link to access Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD">
Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD
</a>
</h3>
```

What I'm after is getting the "Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD" part.

Comment: Yes, i tried a useful function for getting strings between tags but that doesnt really work in this case.

Comment: show your attempts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parser example:

```
$string = '<h3 class="lvtitle"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Chicago-Chicago-XXX-Audio-CD-/351478948979?hash=item51d5c72473"  class="vip" title="Click this link to access Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD">Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD</a></h3>';
$doc = new DOMDocument(); //make a dom object
$doc->loadHTML($string); // load the string into the object
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); //get all links
foreach ($links as $link) { //loop through all links
    echo $link->nodeValue; //output text content of links
}
```

Output:

> Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

...or if you really required a regex for some reason ( I don't see why parser wouldn't work)...

```
$string = '<h3 class="lvtitle"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/Chicago-Chicago-XXX-Audio-CD-/351478948979?hash=item51d5c72473"  class="vip" title="Click this link to access Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD">Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD</a></h3>';
preg_match_all('~<a\h.*?>(.*?)</a>~', $string, $links_content);
print_r($links_content[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Chicago, Chicago XXX Audio CD
)
```

`~` = delimiter 
`<a` = literally match `<a`
`\h` = a horizontal white space
`.*?` = anything untile the first occurrence of the next character
`>` =  a literal `>`
`(.*?)` = a capture grouping capturing everything until the next character again
`</a>` = literal `</a>`
`~` = closing delimiter

If you prefer regex101 write up, https://regex101.com/r/sT6yA9/1.

Also note the `preg_match_all` that was incase your string had multiple links in it. With a single occurrence you could use `preg_match`.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen in a while. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are kind of limited in this case, as they cannot be aware of commented text areas, etc.

A simple approach using regular expressions could however look like this:

```
.*"Click this link to access (.*?)".*
```

http://regexr.com/3bjgn

Comment: @molnarpw you are welcome. If this solved you problem, then feel free to mark the answer as "accepted". If you liked the answer, give it a +1! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the link's text

```
^.*?<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

Here is the test results:
https://regex101.com/r/xZ6kJ1/1